# Dynamically get resource object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added all country flags to my Resource class, all having the name like: `flag_TLD` - `flag_de`, `flag_dk` and so on.

For the users, I store the TLD of their country and I want to dynamically display in a list all their country flags.

Usually, when using resources, I use: `GUI.Properties.Resources.<resourcename>` but now I want to use `GUI.Properties.Resources.flag_<user.getCountry.TLD>` in a loop for 50-100 users (as for example).

```
foreach (var user in getUserList())
{
     something.Image = GUI.Properties.Resources.flag_<user.getCountry.TLD>
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the list of all resources in your application the following way:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe; 
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string [] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

All you would have to do now is loop through `resources` and use the elements that contain `flag_` in their names.

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287526(v=vs.71).aspx

**EDIT:**
In order to get a resource based on a string, use

```
 something.Image = GUI.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flag_" + user.getCountry.TLD)
```

Comment: The problem is not the name. I know that `flag_XX` exist